# Calculate the time difference of data in the same column

Tags: powerbi

[image: I have this set of data which i want to calculate the time difference between each 2 consecutive rows]
I have this set of data which i want to calculate the time difference between each 2 consecutive rows.

this in transform data tab i've tried code from chatgpt but didn't work.
if it helps each text that ends with executed by and have open in the text should be minus from the open control message and same for the close messages

Comment: calculations like these should not be done in Power Query. That is what the Data Model and the way more powerful DAX formulas are for. If you need the difference in Power Query, you may want to change the table structure, so that start and end are in the same row and you can do a simple calculation.

Comment: Use OFFSET to imitate LAG() in T-SQL?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNdfs2BRid8